# java.lng.Exception: `Input not an X.509 certificate` when importing .pem certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, keytool

I have created a self-signed certificate with `makecert`, exported it with private key to `.pfx` file and imported on the server. Then I copied one on the client and tried importing it using `keytool`. Got an error `Input is not an X.509 certificate`. 
So I converted `.pfx` certificate to `.pem` using `openssl` and tried again - same result.

I did some research and found that I might need to convert it to `.der`, but it still might not work. Apparently `keytool` only supports single certificate `PEM` files. Even though mine is a single certificate, `PEM` file contains private key information:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----
-----END PRIVATE KEY------


----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
----END CERTIFICATE-------
```

So I am not sure what should be my next step to ensure import will work when done with `keytool` on the client. 
Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: In an editor, delete all the lines before "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" line. So everything outside "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" certificate should be removed, but those header and footer lines should remain.

Comment: what about the private key?

Comment: That's not a certificate, is it? Are you trying to make a trust entry or an identification entry?

Comment: do I need to somehow separate the private key entry from certificate entry? perhaps create 2 files out of one?  What I am trying to do is to install certificate on the client that will be calling my WCF service

Comment: You shouldn't put the server's private key anywhere but the server. The client just needs the certificate in a trust entry to authenticate the server.

Comment: So I can just edit out the private key info?

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: Could you please post your first comment as an answer so i could accept it?